# PowerBi - how to authenticate to app.powerbi.com silently

Tags: powerbi

I have tried the method outlined in the Microsoft docs

which involves creating an app in Active Directory and then having code something very similar to:

```
var authContextUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextUrl);
var redirectUri = "https://dev.powerbi.com/Apps/SignInRedirect";
var pp = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);
var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(PowerBiApiResource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), pp).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

if (result == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the PowerBI API token");
}

var token = result.AccessToken;
return token;
```

I got this code working but it always insisted on prompting for a username and password, which is a problem for a function app.

I have also tried the approach in the silent function specified here

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Data-Refresh-by-using-API-Need-Steps/m-p/209371#M6614

```
   static string getAccessTokenSilently()
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token");
        //POST web request to create a datasource.
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //Add token to the request header
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

        NameValueCollection parsedQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        parsedQueryString.Add("client_id", clientID);
        parsedQueryString.Add("grant_type", "password");
        parsedQueryString.Add("resource", resourceUri);
        parsedQueryString.Add("username", username);
        parsedQueryString.Add("password", password);
        string postdata = parsedQueryString.ToString();


        //POST web request
        byte[] dataByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata); ;
        request.ContentLength = dataByteArray.Length;

        //Write JSON byte[] into a Stream
        using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writer.Write(dataByteArray, 0, dataByteArray.Length);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);
            return responseJson["access_token"];
        }


    }
```

This code doesn't work.

Also this has issues, although I haven't tried it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token

There doesn't appear to be anything up to date available that works that explains how to do this. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Just to be clear, I would like to be able to authenticate silently against an Azure AD application with the appropriate permissions, not have to use a powerBI userId Pro user id and password, unless I really have to (I'm using PowerBI embedded).

Comment: I think I'm missing something... When you use AcquireToken with user credentials, you still authenticate yourself in the context of the registered application, with its permissions, etc. What do you mean you don't want to use Power BI's credentials? They won't give you the user's rights not covered by those granted to the application.

Comment: If I access the Azure management API, I can use an application ID and a password to authenticate to that and get a token. This doesn't appear to be the case here. There doesn't appear to be any way of entering a password and the correct permissions in the same app. I am creating the app from the powerbi web interface, so presumably I have to use a PowerBI Pro username and password.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've got so far. I have to create the application in AD using https://dev.powerbi.com/apps and then login using a powerbi pro userid and password, using the following code:

```
public static string GetPowerBiAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string userId, string password)
{
    var url = $"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var dataToPost = new Dictionary<string,string>
    {
        {"client_id", clientId},
        {"grant_type", "password"},
        {"resource", PowerBiApiResource},
        {"username", userId},
        {"password", password},
        {"redirect_uri", "https://dev.powerbi.com/Apps/SignInRedirect" }
    };

    var postData = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in dataToPost)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData))
            postData += "&";
        postData += $"{item.Key}={item.Value}";
    }

    var dataByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = dataByteArray.Length;

    using (var writer = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        writer.Write(dataByteArray, 0, dataByteArray.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);
    return responseJson["access_token"];
}
```

(P.S. I appreciate the request part of this code could be much better but having spent over 2 days trying to work this out, I'm just glad to have something that is working right now. Also the redirectUrl matches the one in my app, I'm not sure if its essential or not).

In the event of errors, I used Fiddler 4 to tell me exactly what the error was rather than just getting 400 or 401 in the app.